# What is the difference between 变成、变化、变得、改变、转变?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, vocabulary, difference

There are five 变 here, so what is the difference between 变成、变化、变得、改变、转变?

Answer (score 11):

I think I really need more context to tell the differences. Sometimes they are  interchangeable.

## `变成` -> Become / Turn into

五年过去了，我从一个学生变成了一名老师 - I was a student. After 5 years I am a teacher now.

## `变化` -> Difference / Change (mostly used as noun)

五年过去了，这里还是没有什么变化 - After 5 years there's nothing changed.

## `变得` -> It's like `变成` but it should be used before a adjective/adverb.

五年过去了，我变得越来越谨慎了 - After 5 years I'm getting more and more careful

## `改变` -> Change (verb/noun)

她想改变自己的生活 - She wants to change her life (she wants to have a new lifestyle)

## `转变` -> Seldom used. Sometimes A more formal version of 改变

专家建议毕业生们转变就业观念 - Experts advice graduates to change their thoughts on getting a job.

Comment: This answer seems really good to me. It matches both my 語感 (non-native but advanced learner) and what I have seen/heard from people who rely on considerably more than a feeling. Great!

Comment: In this case is 得 in 变得 considered a degree complement?

Comment: 转变 often refers to changes from bad/negative thinking/behavior to good/positive ones